# Merging the results of two background workers upon completion

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

i have two background threads

```
Worker = new BackgroundWorker();
Worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(GetQuery);
Worker.RunWorkerCompleted += GetQuery_RunWorkerCompleted;
Worker.RunWorkerAsync();

Worker2012 = new BackgroundWorker();
Worker2012.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(GetQuery2012);
Worker2012.RunWorkerCompleted += GetQuery2012_RunWorkerCompleted;
Worker2012.RunWorkerAsync();
```

both the methods in worker threads are returning data tables

now my task is i need to merge those two data tables into one

for that reason i am doing this in the RunCompletion of the first task

```
void GetQuerys_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   do{} while(Worker2012.IsBusy);
   //Merge Datatables
}
```

but for some reason the do while loop seems to be in infinite loop. the thread does not end. can some one tell me what i am doing wrong. or is there a better way to wait for the second worker thread to get complete so that i can merge data. any help would be appreciated

Comment: i did try that. gave a sleep of 2 seconds but still it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that .NET 4.5 is out, I recommend that everyone use `Task.Run` instead of `BackgroundWorker`, as such:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => GetQuery());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => GetQuery2012());
var dataTables = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
// Merge databases
```

`Task.Run` is superior to `BackgroundWorker` in every way, and this is particularly noticeable when doing anything complex (i.e., coordinating two background operations).

Comment: The result of `await Task.WhenAll` is void, you can't assign that to `dataTables`

Comment: awesome this just works perfectly fine with very few lines of code. thanks stephen

Comment: @dcastro: `await Task.WhenAll` will return an array of results (`TResult[]`) *if* all its arguments are `Task<TResult>` (with the same `TResult`).

Comment: Sorry about that, I was looking at the wrong overload in the msdn docs!

Comment: SAmple for getquery?

Comment: @Kiquenet: `GetQuery` is from the OP's question, not my code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using TPL instead, making it much more readable:

```
Task query1 = GetQuery();
Task query2 = GetQuery2012();

Task.WhenAll(query1, query2).ContinueWith( t => {

  //merge

});
```

You can also do `await Task.WhenAll()...` if you want the main thread to (asynchronously) wait for the tables to be merged.

Make sure you change your `Query` methods to something like this:

```
public Task GetQuery() {
  return Task.Run( () => {
    //do background work
  });    
}
```

**Edit**
I just noticed something that might go wrong with this.

The ContinueWith task will (most likely) not run in the UI thread.

If you need to merge the tables in the UI thread, then you should do this instead:

```
public void UIMethod() {
    Task query1 = GetQuery();
    Task query2 = GetQuery2012();

    await Task.WhenAll(query1, query2); //will free the thread until both tasks complete
    MergeTables();
}
```

This way, the `MergeTables()` method will run on the UI thread.

Comment: Why not? If you do `await Task.WhenAll()...` your UI thread will be free to execute other stuff, and your method will regain control when both tasks finish. And if you don't `await`, your UI thread will simply carry on. TPL is specifically designed for this.

Comment: Results for  getquery methods?