# How to check if multiple background workers completed and to update the UI thread?

Tags: wpf

I am creating a `WPF` application to collect logs. I am using different `Backgroundworker` to execute some scripts. Worker1 for script1, Worker2 for script2 and so on. When `Backgroundworker` completes `RunworkerCompleted` method get executed.

So, how can I wait for all the workers to complete? Once all these workers are complete, I need to update the `UI` thread.

Comment: You should be using MVVM instead of updating the UI.

Comment: hey, did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Tasks.

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do something
    }
);

Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do something
    }
);

Task t3 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do something
    }
);

await Task.WhenAll(new Task[] { t1, t2, t3 }).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        // Do something when all three tasks have completed...
    }        
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to wait for all `BackgroundWorker` objects to get complete. I hope you are using `C#`:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int noOfbackgroundWorker = 5;
        WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[noOfbackgroundWorker];
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfbackgroundWorker; i++)
        {
            var bg1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
            bg1.DoWork += delegate(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) { Thread.Sleep(i * 1000); };
            bg1.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) { handle.Set(); };
            waitHandles[i] = handle;
            bg1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
        Console.WriteLine("Done in "+sw.Elapsed.Seconds + " seconds");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Apart from above if there is low no of `BackgroundWorker`, just set a `bool` variable for each worker to map each worker complete status and call a common method from all `RunworkerCompleted` event handler that just has condition `if(a && b && c.....)` if passed then notify the `UI`.

Answer (score 0):

As I say in my [`Task.Run` vs `BackgroundWorker` conclusion](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-conclusion.html):

> anything like [waiting for two separate background operations to complete before doing something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659124/merging-the-results-of-two-background-workers-upon-completion/18659509#18659509) is much easier with `Task.Run`. Pretty much any time you have to *coordinate* background operations, `Task.Run` code is going to be *much* simpler!

(this is the conclusion of a [series of blog posts comparing `Task.Run` to `BackgroundWorker`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html)).

> Worker1 for script1, Worker2 for script2 and so on.

You can do this with `Task.Run`:

```
Result DoWork(Script script) { ... }

IEnumerable<Script> scripts = ...;
var tasks = scripts.Select(x => Task.Run(() => DoWork(x))).ToList();
```

> So, how can I wait for all the workers to complete? Once all these workers are complete, I need to update the UI thread.

Use `await` and `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
... // Update UI with results
```